# How to integrate Spotify to commercial project? Android and iOS users

Tags: integration, spotify

At the beginning, I want to apologize for non-developer question. I wasn't able ask this on Meta, because Meta requires 5 reputation just to be able ask any questions.

Question: We want to integrate Spotify for commercial project for Android and iOS users to make them able use music through Spotify. 
So where we can get Spotify's approval? How we can sign a contract to start cooperation? 
We asked this on Facebook in Spotify official page, they sent us here to ask these.
On the Spotify's website, no email to contact for.

With respect,
Rus
Operation department

Answer (score 0):

Arielle from Spotify here.

If you create a application in the Dashboard on Spotify for Developers (https://beta.developer.spotify.com/dashboard/), you will be prompted to go through a commercial request form, which will ask you for more information about your app. The appropriate teams can then follow up about your request.

Comment: thank you so much for answering my question and providing a link. We already submit a commercial form from that link.  My company(Kwai) have been waiting for a month, but Spotify didn't reply anything. We already don't know how to get connect with Spotify, because we want to offer commercial integration with this service, which will be financially profitable for them.

Comment: Could you please give us some advice in this situation? Who else we could to get contact to start somehow cooperation?

Comment: The commercial review process can take several months, and unfortunately, I can only ask for your patience.

Comment: when I try to access the link in rewrites the url to the normal dashboard, could you tell me where to find the button to start the review process? Or doesn't it exist anymore?

Comment: ah sorry :) just read that you have to create a new app to declare it as commercial, no way to add an already existing one?